# Does this violate the Single Responsibility Principle?

Tags: java, oop, single-responsibility-principle

I am trying to write code to make a simple game.

Assuming that there is a class called Level in which it manages the functionalities for the level.

For example, there are some methods like spawnHero() and spawnEnemies(), start(), finish() and etc in the class.

if I put a private String method called PrettyTimeFormat that converts the game duration time into a nicely arranged format and uses it in the finish() method, would this violate the SRP?

If so, should I make a class called TimeManager and put the PrettyTimeformat method in that class in order to avoid SRP?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you try to stick to SRP at all cost? Patterns are nice but not always appropriate. As a programmer you need to be able to understand the reasoning behind a pattern and find a middle ground. Not trying to argue against it, just curious.

Comment: Formatting time is not the `Level`'s responsibility, but it doesn't expose this to anything else, so it's not a "true" responsibility of the `Level`. Dedicated time manager component would be better still, but not because of SRP - that way you can give your game a time manager that works differently (for example, for a test), and you would not have to change any line of code in `Level` doing that.

Comment: Its hard to give a good design advice with that little detail on the whole project. At this stage, I would tend to say that any answer is likely very broad and not specific enough or opinion based and thus not within the scope defined by StackOverflow. As such, voting to close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a `Game` object. `Game` has `Level`, `Hero`, `Enemies`, and `GameTime`. `Game` can be `start()`-ed and `finish()`-ed.

When you architect the solution think about real objects. [Objects exist in real life](https://www.yegor256.com/2014/11/20/seven-virtues-of-good-object.html), are living things that do real things and [don't create objects that end with -er.](https://www.yegor256.com/2015/03/09/objects-end-with-er.html)

Comment: *"Don't create objects that end with -er."* Very debatable advice. Since we're talking about the single responsibility principle, a class named FileReader has a very clearly-defined single responsibility (it reads from a file), for example.

Comment: I took a broader look at what the OP is asking. But I agree, there are two schools of thoughts.